# Laravel array filtering

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, filter

Developers, I am working on a report that I have to display the companies ranking based on some conditions for the date range which comes from front. Ex: last week, I have done that, but now I want to show how many weeks that a particular company be in same rank. If I am checking the past week I have to check the ranking for each week from the year start. If last week first position company and other weeks first position company is same I have make the count as increasing accordingly. When I querying the data for each week using the for loop it is taking around 42s to process and display the data. Also I tried to fetch whole data from first week of the year to current week then I filtered the array but this also takes long time. Can anyone give any other ideas to overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some code of what you tried

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem - then storage of aggregated data should help you.

1. Create a table in the database, let's say "archive_rating", with 3 fields: week_number (let from January 1, 2000), company_id, company_position in your rating. Don't forget the index for the week_number field.
2. At 00:00:00 every Monday, run a background task that will save the positions for each company to an archive table.

This will allow you not to calculate a rating for each week from the beginning of the year. You will already have it.